# The button doesn't appear in firefox 12

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have created this simple button but it doesn't appear in firefox 12:

```
  <toolbarpalette id="BrowserToolbarPalette">

      <toolbarbutton id="ok-nav"
                     class="toolbarbutton-1 chromeclass-toolbar-additional"
                     label="&okok;"
                     tooltiptext="&okok;">
      </toolbarbutton>

  </toolbarpalette>
```

Why ?

Comment: Where does it not appear? In the customize toolbar dialog? Which files are you overlaying? I think you need to add a little context :)

Answer (score 0):

`<toolbarbutton>` is a self-ending element; you don't need a closing tag, the same as with normal `<input>` elements in HTML. I'm not sure if this is what's causing the problem, but it's your best bet.

Comment: Thank you, I have removed the closing tag but I get the same problem. On firefox 11 it works well but in ff12 not :(

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not sure then. Could be the `chromeless-toolbar-additional` class preventing it displaying? I'm not sure what styles it defines.

Comment: I forgotten the trailing slash /  in the toolbar button tag. Now it works :D